# profiler for slow javascript (jquery) on page event? "Unresponsive Script" error

Tags: javascript, debugging, profiling, profiler

I am troubleshooting some slow jquery code on a drupal module. After the page loads on a configuration form, you click on an area to expand out a fieldform. However, this expansion takes forever, and most browser give a warning "The script has become unresponsive, do you want to stop it?"

I'm looking for a profiler that will give output like that from xdebug, where I can see the statistics of the entire execution path, just for that one javascript event.

The debugger in firebug will drop me in on the exact line where firefox decides that the script is taking too long; but there is no single line that is the problem (at least I don't think so at this point). I believe that the slowdown comes from some poorly-architectured looping or iteration that spans multiple lines, which is why I want the profiler stats to show me in what parts of the code its spending most of the time.

Comment: Have you tried the Firebug profiler?  Personally I haven't had much luck with it, but it might be worth a quick look. Chrome also has a profiler that seems a little better.

Comment: @Pointy I didn't realize that firebug had a profiler. Please post that and I will upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Firebug add-on has a profiler built into it.  I don't have Firebug installed on the machine I'm using right now, but if I recall it's accessed from a pull-down menu in the "Console" view. (I could be wrong; it's there somewhere.)  I can't say that I'm super-fond of it, but you might want to give it a try.

Chrome's developer tools also has a profiler, which is a little fancier.

For IE, there's a product called [dynaTrace AJAX edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/), which has a *really* fancy profiler. Of course it only works with IE, but you're going to have to test in IE anyway — if you've got a page that's slow in other browsers, it's going to be even worse in IE :-)